# Json.NET populates one class, but not another

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to populate my object `ParticleSystem` object using Json.Net like this:

```
public void LoadJson(string path, object targetObject)
{
   using (var sw = new StreamReader(path))
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(sw))
            JsonHelpers.DefaultSerializer.Populate(reader, targetObject);
}
```

with the following json file:

```
{
  "TexturePath": "Particles/snow",
  "MaxParticles": 8500
}
```

Here is part of the class (the whole thing is too large to post)

```
public class ParticleSystem : Entity3D
{
        public int MaxParticles;
        public string TexturePath { get; set; } = "Textures/default_diffuse";

        public void Load()
        {
            LoadJson("Data/Particles/SnowSettings.json", this);
        }
        etc...
}
```

Howver, any which way I try to call the `LoadJson()` method, no values are populated into the object.

When I make a new class as such, and call it in the exact same way, the class is populated exactly as expected using the same file and same method. I've added a few parent classes to test if inheritance breaks anything, as the original class has several inheritances.

```
    class TestClass : sub<float>
    {
        public int MaxParticles;
        public string TexturePath { get; set; } = "Textures/default_diffuse";

        public void Load()
        {
            LoadJson("Data/Particles/SnowSettings.json", this);
        }
    }
    class sub<T> : sub2
    {

    }
    class sub2
    {

    }
```

What can be causing this? I've enabled error logging, but I get nothing. Is there any way to get a log of what is/isn't being populated? Or how can I debug this and find the reason for the original not geting populated?

**Edit & Answer:**

After investigation in the quite complex hierarchy trees that this was part of, and thus could not fully be posted, I finally found what was causing my problem. It turns out one of the base classes had the attribute:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
```

which has the following description

> Only members marked with Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute or
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute are serialized. This
>   member serialization mode can also be set by marking the class with
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute.

While I can see how that affects serialization, it think it's not completely clear that that also includes deseriaization and even the `Populate()` methods ignore them even though they are present in the JSON file. I would think this should at least be logged in the Tracer to find such behaviour.

I've marked the answer to enable a `Tracer` as answer and provide these details here for my specific case, as that answer answered the actual question that I asked.

Comment: Could you post one single [mcve]? Your code does not compile and/or has gaps that we have to guess.

Comment: It's difficult to reproduce since the classes are long and part of long hierarchies, so I completely understand it's hard to reproduce and debug. The code examples are more to give a bit of context. That's why I'm asking for any possible reasons, and a way to get error/logs from `Populate` so I can see if anything is going wrong. If there is no other way I may have to try to extract and reproduce the code, but I think it's somehow connected to the complexity of the class.

Comment: " no values are populated into the object." Is this inside the LoadJson method or the calling object?  Shouldn't you be passing byref on the 'this' object if you want the changes to exist outside the LoadJson call?

Comment: *What can be causing this?* -- we need to see a [mcve] to help you.  If you are asking us to **guess** it could be 1) You have some read-only properties that are populated only via a parameterized constructor, which is not called by `Populate()` because the object is already constructed; 2) Your root object has a `JsonConverter`, but the root object's converter is never used by `Populate()`; 3) You have a `JsonConverter` at a lower level whose `ReadJson()` method is not correctly using the incoming `existingValue`; 4) Or something else.  We can't really answer a question that isn't concrete.

Comment: It falls on you to create a [MCVE] Start from scratch create a hierarchy of two simple classes and see if you get the behavior you see in your real example. If yes post it. If not, try to add one by one some of the particularities of the real example. E.g. add private fields, add readony fields, add constructors until you get in the MCVE the behavior you see in the real example. But all this **you need to do**. That's what creating a MCVE means.

Comment: As I explained twice I understand that I need to provide a MCV example to be able to pinpoint the exact problem. The class is part of a large hierarchy tree and rebuilding it would take considerable time. I don't understand the downvoting of this question as I've seen heaps of less specific questions with upvotes. My question was how I can debug this better and in which general direction I should look, which thankfully was answered by you dbc and nvoigt. This question does provide great insight and is **useful** and for others that have similar problems. See edit for my solution.

Comment: Besides, as stated in the references MCV page three times _When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, **you will get much better answers** if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem._, not that is a requirement, makes it unanswerable or should be downvoted, especially since my original question wasn't to pinpoint the exact problem. @bolov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out what goes wrong in serialization, you can use [tracing](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationTracing.htm).

Set the `TraceWriter` property of the serializer to a tracewriter you can scan for suspicious messages.

For example:

```
public void LoadJson(string path, object targetObject)
{
   using (var sw = new StreamReader(path))
   {
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(sw))
        {
            var traceWriter = new MemoryTraceWriter();
            var serializer = JsonHelpers.DefaultSerializer;

            serializer.TraceWriter = traceWriter;
            serializer.Populate(reader, targetObject);

            Console.WriteLine(traceWriter);
        }
    }
}
```

This is not exactly best practice, but it should give you a hint what your problem is during debugging.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. However the tracewriter doesn't seem to be reporting any errors, yet non of the properties are being populated? The log looks like this:
`2018-09-14T17:08:04.753 Info Started deserializing jsmars.Game3D.ParticleSystem. Path 'BlendState', line 2, position 15.
2018-09-14T17:08:04.760 Info Finished deserializing jsmars.Game3D.ParticleSystem. Path '', line 40, position 1.` plus the full JSON file after

Comment: Does the debug message look different for the smaller object that works?

Comment: It does in fact! The working object lists all of the custom converters I'm using. Very peculiar. Any reason for this? Here are both logs: https://pastebin.com/EXk0ig9M

Comment: I've marked this as answer as it answers my question on how I can get more logging, details for my solution is edited into my question.